# CentOS7 Kerberos Auth: Improper format of Kerberos configuration file;

Tags: centos, security, samba, squid, kerberos

I'm working on setting up a `Squid 4.0` explicit proxy for group based AD authentication against a Active Directory domain (Server 2012 R2) with SSL bumping on a minimal CentOS 7 (64b) install.

The domain join was very sketchy using `authconfig-tui` but I managed to get it basically configured so AD users can authenticate via `SSH`, the Squid proxy works with authentication turned off. But `kinit` fails with:

```
[root@tc-icap squid]# kinit
kinit: Improper format of Kerberos configuration file while initializing Kerberos 5 library
```

After upping the debug logging for Squid and attempting to authenticate using a domain joined client, I see this in Squid's `cache.log`:

```
2016/03/02 11:12:56.151| Starting new negotiateauthenticator helpers...
2016/03/02 11:12:56.151| helperOpenServers: Starting 1/10 'negotiate_kerberos_auth' processes
2016/03/02 11:12:56| negotiate_kerberos_auth: ERROR: krb5_init_context: Improper format of Kerberos configuration file
2016/03/02 11:12:56| negotiate_kerberos_auth: ERROR: krb5_init_context: Improper format of Kerberos configuration file
2016/03/02 11:12:56.151| ERROR: Negotiate Authentication validating user.   Result: {result=BH, notes={message: gss_acquire_cred() failed: An invalid name was supplied. Improper format of Kerberos configuration file; }}
2016/03/02 11:12:56.169| 11,5| HttpRequest.cc(473) detailError: current error details: 2/0
```

I really can't find what is wrong with my `/etc/krb5.conf` file. How should I proceed?

`krb5.conf`:

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = yes
 dns_lookup_kdc = yes
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 default_realm = LAB.COMPANYDOMAIN.COM
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
LAB.COMPANYDOMAIN.COM {
  kdc = TC-DC1.LAB.COMPANYDOMAIN.COM
  kdc = TC-DC2.LAB.COMPANYDOMAIN.COM
  admin_server = TC-DC1.LAB.COMPANYDOMAIN.COM
  default_domain = lab.companydomain.com
}

[domain_realm]
  .lab.companydomain.com = LAB.COMPANYDOMAIN.COM
  lab.companydomain.com = LAB.COMPANYDOMAIN.COM
```

`squid.conf`:

```
# Squid 4 Explicit Proxy Configuration File
# 
# Goals:
#   1. Install Minimal CentOS 7 VM to host Squid
#   2. Configure Squid for explicit proxying with the following features:
#      a. ICAP (Content Adaptation) integration with CA Data Protection 15.0
#      b. SSL Bumping (Peek and Splice -- Most recent and flexible configuration)
#      c. Active Directory / LDAP Authentication and filtering rules
#      d. User information pass-through to ICAP Agent (for mapping policy to authenticated users)
#      e. Attempt content blocking / data in motion capture
#   3. Test functionality of intercepting Outlook Anywhere connectivity (without breaking clients.)
#   4. AD Group based access control and possibly blacklisting
#   5. Integration with Windows Certificate Authority services to generate certs/key requests
#   6. Kerberos / WINBIND authentication if AD/LDAP doesn't work. (kinit/keychain issues currently)
#
# Nice to haves:
#   1. ECAP (Encrypted ICAP support.) Squid has this, ICAP Agent does not.
#   2. Debug why ICAP URI's fail with DNS entries instead of IP address
#   3. Test fail open / closed configurations
#   4. Experiment with transparent proxying of traffic (avoid end user proxy configuration)
#   5. ICAP Content Adaptation Chain (Squeeze ClamAV in before or after DataProtection agent)
#   6. Automated auto-configuration deployment
#   7. Inject custom web X-Headers, check if headers are available as XML Data Lookups in Data Protection
#
# Reminder:
#   1. Check and reload configuration changes in Squid without restarting via:
#      squid -k check
#      squid -k reconfigure

# Debug logging: (very noisy!)
debug_options ALL,1 11,6


acl localnet src 0.0.0.1-0.255.255.255  # RFC 1122 "this" network (LAN)
acl localnet src 10.0.0.0/8             # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 100.64.0.0/10          # RFC 6598 shared address space (CGN)
acl localhet src 169.254.0.0/16         # RFC 3927 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 172.16.0.0/12          # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src 192.168.0.0/16         # RFC 1918 local private network (LAN)
acl localnet src fc00::/7               # RFC 4193 local private network range
acl localnet src fe80::/10              # RFC 4291 link-local (directly plugged) machines
acl localnet src 25.0.0.0/8             # Hamachi local subnet (when installed)

acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

# Enable Kerberos authentication, basic LDAP auth as fallback, block anonymous
auth_param negotiate program /usr/lib64/squid/negotiate_kerberos_auth -s HTTP/TC-ICAP.LAB.companydomain.com@LAB.COMPANYDOMAIN.COM     #???
auth_param negotiate children 10 startup=0 idle=1
auth_param negotiate keep_alive off
auth_param basic program /usr/lib64/squid/basic_ldap_auth -R -b "dc=lab,dc=companydomain,dc=com" -D squidproxy@lab.companydomain.com -w Welcome1 -f (|userPrincipalName=%s)(sAMAccountName=%s)) -h tc-dc1.lab.companydomain.com
auth_param basic children 10
auth_param basic realm Internet Proxy
auth_param basic credentialsttl 1 minute
acl auth proxy_auth REQUIRED

# Recommended minimum Access Permission configuration:
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
http_access deny to_localhost
http_access deny !auth
http_access allow auth
http_access deny all

http_access allow localnet
http_access allow localhost

#
# Squid/DataProtection ACL's, ICAP Directives, Bumping cert directives
#
httpd_suppress_version_string on
sslcrtd_program /usr/lib64/squid/ssl_crtd -s /etc/squid/ssl_cert/ssl_db -M 12MB
sslcrtd_children 10
acl HTTP proto HTTP
always_direct allow all
#ssl_bump server-first all
ssl_bump stare all
ssl_bump bump all
sslproxy_cert_error allow all
sslproxy_cert_error allow all

icap_enable on
icap_send_client_ip on
icap_send_client_username on
icap_preview_enable off
icap_preview_size -1
icap_persistent_connections on
#icap_client_username_encode on
#icap_client_username_header X-Authenticated-User
# BK - Let us try using the IP address instead of DNS entries
icap_service sreq reqmod_precache icap://10.1.1.52:1344/reqmod
icap_service sresp respmod_precache icap://10.1.1.52:1344/respmod
adaptation_service_set aclreq sreq
adaptation_service_set aclresp sresp
adaptation_access aclreq allow all
adaptation_access aclresp allow all

# Deny requests that are not covered in above ACLs
http_access deny all

# The magic happens here:
# Directives: ssl-bump, generate dynamic certs, point to cert, path to sslcrtd??????
http_port 3128 ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=12MB cert=/etc/squid/ssl_cert/myCA.pem
#http_port 3128         # This is the default

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

# Note: Default refresh patterns below. Research these later for other protocols?
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
```

`sssd.conf`:

```
[sssd]
domains = LAB.companydomain.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/LAB.companydomain.com]
ad_domain = LAB.companydomain.com
krb5_realm = LAB.COMPANYDOMAIN.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
```

`realm list` and `net ads info`:

```
[root@tc-icap squid]# net ads info
LDAP server: 10.1.1.20
LDAP server name: TC-DC1.LAB.companydomain.com
Realm: LAB.COMPANYDOMAIN.COM
Bind Path: dc=LAB,dc=COMPANYDOMAIN,dc=COM
LDAP port: 389
Server time: Wed, 02 Mar 2016 11:43:10 EST
KDC server: 10.1.1.20
Server time offset: 0


[root@tc-icap squid]# realm list
LAB.companydomain.com
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: LAB.COMPANYDOMAIN.COM
  domain-name: lab.companydomain.com
  configured: kerberos-member
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: oddjob
  required-package: oddjob-mkhomedir
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common
  login-formats: %U
  login-policy: allow-realm-logins
```

*Edit:* Here's a `strace kinit` to hopefully find a little more information about why Krb5 thinks that the file is invalid:

```
[root@tc-icap ~]# strace kinit
execve("/usr/bin/kinit", ["kinit"], [/* 25 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x7f9c4ee5d000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4db29000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=38289, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 38289, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4db1f000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libkadm5srv_mit.so.9", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20o\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=121120, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2255200, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4d6e2000
mprotect(0x7f9c4d6fd000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4d8fd000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b000) = 0x7f9c4d8fd000
mmap(0x7f9c4d8ff000, 39264, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4d8ff000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libkdb5.so.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0PF\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=79128, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2172848, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4d4cf000
mprotect(0x7f9c4d4e1000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4d6e0000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x11000) = 0x7f9c4d6e0000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libgssrpc.so.4", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000[\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=134344, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4db1e000
mmap(NULL, 2227080, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4d2af000
mprotect(0x7f9c4d2cd000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4d4cd000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e000) = 0x7f9c4d4cd000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\300\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=316528, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2406656, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4d063000
mprotect(0x7f9c4d0ac000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4d2ac000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x49000) = 0x7f9c4d2ac000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libkrb5.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0PK\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=950496, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3033216, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4cd7e000
mprotect(0x7f9c4ce53000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4d053000, 65536, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xd5000) = 0x7f9c4d053000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0pG\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=202576, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4db1d000
mmap(NULL, 2298360, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4cb4c000
mprotect(0x7f9c4cb7b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4cd7a000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2e000) = 0x7f9c4cd7a000
mmap(0x7f9c4cd7d000, 504, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4cd7d000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libcom_err.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0p\25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=15840, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109928, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4c948000
mprotect(0x7f9c4c94b000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4cb4a000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f9c4cb4a000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\3406\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=62720, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2156136, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4c739000
mprotect(0x7f9c4c746000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4c946000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xd000) = 0x7f9c4c946000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libkeyutils.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=15688, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4db1c000
mmap(NULL, 2109720, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4c535000
mprotect(0x7f9c4c538000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4c737000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f9c4c737000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libresolv.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0@:\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=110808, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2202264, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4c31b000
mprotect(0x7f9c4c331000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4c531000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f9c4c531000
mmap(0x7f9c4c533000, 6808, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4c533000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240d\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=147120, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2246784, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4c0f6000
mprotect(0x7f9c4c117000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4c317000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x21000) = 0x7f9c4c317000
mmap(0x7f9c4c319000, 6272, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4c319000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\320\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=19520, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4db1b000
mmap(NULL, 2109744, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4bef2000
mprotect(0x7f9c4bef5000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4c0f4000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f9c4c0f4000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2107816, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3932736, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4bb31000
mprotect(0x7f9c4bce7000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4bee7000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b6000) = 0x7f9c4bee7000
mmap(0x7f9c4beed000, 16960, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4beed000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240l\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=142304, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4db1a000
mmap(NULL, 2208864, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4b915000
mprotect(0x7f9c4b92b000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4bb2b000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7f9c4bb2b000
mmap(0x7f9c4bb2d000, 13408, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4bb2d000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/libpcre.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\360\25\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=398272, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2490888, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4b6b4000
mprotect(0x7f9c4b714000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4b913000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x5f000) = 0x7f9c4b913000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib64/liblzma.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0000/\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=153192, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2245240, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4b48f000
mprotect(0x7f9c4b4b3000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f9c4b6b2000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x23000) = 0x7f9c4b6b2000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4db19000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4db18000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4db16000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f9c4db16840) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4bee7000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4bb2b000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4b6b2000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4b913000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4c0f4000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4c317000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4c531000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4c737000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4c946000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4cb4a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4cd7a000, 8192, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4d053000, 53248, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4d2ac000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4d4cd000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4d6e0000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4d8fd000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4dd32000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f9c4db2a000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f9c4db1f000, 38289)           = 0
set_tid_address(0x7f9c4db16b10)         = 1173
set_robust_list(0x7f9c4db16b20, 24)     = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7f9c4b91b780, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f9c4b924100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7f9c4b91b810, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7f9c4b924100}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM64_INFINITY}) = 0
statfs("/sys/fs/selinux", 0x7ffedf4d6310) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
statfs("/selinux", 0x7ffedf4d6310)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
brk(0)                                  = 0x7f9c4ee5d000
brk(0x7f9c4ee7e000)                     = 0x7f9c4ee7e000
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4db28000
read(3, "nodev\tsysfs\nnodev\trootfs\nnodev\tb"..., 1024) = 276
stat("/etc/sysconfig/64bit_strstr_via_64bit_strstr_sse2_unaligned", 0x7ffedf4d61f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
read(3, "", 1024)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f9c4db28000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=106065056, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 106065056, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c44f68000
close(3)                                = 0
ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or SNDRV_TIMER_IOCTL_NEXT_DEVICE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
futex(0x7f9c4c947510, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7f9c4c9473b0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7f9c4d061420, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0x7f9c4d062550, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
stat("/etc/krb5.conf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1003, ...}) = 0
open("/etc/krb5.conf", O_RDONLY)        = 3
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1003, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4db28000
read(3, "[logging]\n default = FILE:/var/l"..., 4096) = 1003
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f9c4db28000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2502, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f9c4db28000
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2502
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f9c4db28000, 4096)            = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/mit-krb5.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/mit-krb5.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en_US/LC_MESSAGES/mit-krb5.mo", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=410, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 410, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f9c4db28000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/usr/share/locale/en.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES/mit-krb5.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/mit-krb5.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/mit-krb5.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
write(2, "kinit: Improper format of Kerber"..., 54kinit: Improper format of Kerberos configuration file ) = 54
write(2, "while initializing Kerberos 5 li"..., 37while initializing Kerberos 5 library) = 37
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: What's this authconfig-tui stuff? The [proper way to join a domain](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Windows_Integration_Guide/realmd-domain.html) is `realm join ad.example.com -U 'AD.EXAMPLE.COM\domainjoininguser'`

Comment: @Michael Hampton, after screwing around with the RHEL 7 Active Directory integration guide, authconfig-tui seemed like the quickest way to get the basics set up, as it supposedly takes care of krb5.conf, sssd.conf, pam/ldap, etc. The case sensitivty on domain names was a brutal troubleshooting task.

Comment: I dunno, 15 seconds seems hard to beat. I think you've probably done more than that by now...

Comment: I'm already joined to the domain, per realm. authconfig-tui does the domain join for you.

Comment: I don't believe you would be having this issue if you were _properly_ joined to the domain! I wish you luck in fixing it, but it would probably be faster and easier to start over.

Comment: I'll start over again (this is attempt #8) later today. I've been down that route multiple times before with mixed success in obtaining AD membership, but no success in Kerberos. Do you see anything wrong with the config files though?

Comment: @Michael Hampton, no luck again. Rebuilt from scratch, same issue, same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After many hours, many different sets of eyes, a dozen rebuilds and rejoins, the #samba freenode channel, and hard liquor, I found the solution.

It turns out that whichever tools associated with the join neglected to add the `=` sign while referencing the `[realm]`.

[image]

The second half of this problem was due to an `sssd-libwbclient` conflict with what ships in CentOS 7.2. Performing a `yum remove sssd-libwbclient` fixed that as well, and `wbinfo` now successfully returns what it is supposed to.

Redhat bug that is related: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1175511

Answer (score 1):

I may not know much about kerberos but I fixed this locally by converting the file into unicode. Everything appears to be working fine. Good luck!

See https://github.com/krb5/krb5/pull/379.

Comment: I will see if I can make this happen. If it works, I owe you a beer. I've literally spent between 16-24 work hours trying to get Kerberos to *just work for once.*

Comment: I used UTF-32, hope it helps!

Comment: thanks but that had no effect. *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

Glad you got it working! Saw your chat earlier on #samba.

You can simplify your krb5.conf further and let AD Sites & Services handle which servers perform authentication, etc by leaving out the [realms] section entirely (and avoid that config issue) if you only have the 1 AD realm. Just specifying the default_realm = X parameter is enough. You also get the benefit that if you ever migrate to new DCs everything doesn't stop working while you reconfigure your krb5.conf's :)

I've also never had to include the [domain_realms] stanza either in a single-domain/realm environment. I've never tested it in a forest or with trusts though.

Answer (score -1):

for me the issue was causes i had Centos 7.2
after yum update Centos updated to 7.3 and it has installed successfully.